# Retrieve minSdkVersion programmatically

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have set the minSdkVersion in the manifest. Now I want to retrieve it in the code. It should be easy but I'm not getting it. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your intent? AFAIK there is no way to retrieve the value, and it doesn't make sense really to do so.

Comment: OMG you know that is easy? But I know 'there is no way'. What are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

minSDKVersion is one of the settings in the Android manifest for which there is no API to read the value.

It's not impossible to get hold of - you just end up having to read the AndroidManifest.xml file yourself via `XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getAssets().openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml")`

and then parsing the appropriate information out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you *probably* actually want to be doing is retrieving the SDK version of the device running the app. It does not make sense to get the `minSdkVersion` in any scenario I can think of, which as far as I know is impossible anyways, because how is it relevant at all to the application being run on the device? What you want is the *device's* SDK version so you can check whether or not it's above a certain version, upon which you can perform some action.

If you indeed want the SDK version of the device you can use `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

Or if you want to support all android versions then `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK`, but the latter will return a `String`, which you should convert to an `int` by `Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK)`.

Comment: I think minSdkVersion could be useful in build verification tests.