# How to get minimum sdk version(minSdkVersion) at runtime?

Tags: android

I wanted to get the `minSdkVersion` used to build the app at runtime. I tried with the below code.

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion
```

In the documentation the `targetSdkVersion` is mentioned with the comment `The minimum SDK version this application targets.`. But it is providing the current version where the application is running.

Is there any predefined way is available to get the `minSdkVersion`? (or) 
Is there any hack is possible to get the `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: Have you tried any of this answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283534/retrieve-minsdkversion-programatically

Comment: targetSdkVersion is the targetSdkVersion declared in the apk.

Comment: @JoeBowbeer I didn't get what you are trying to tell!!

Comment: @MahendranSakkarai The targetSdkVersion in ApplicationInfo was declared in the apk's build.gradle file. It is not the Android version of the device where the apk is running.

Comment: @JoeBowbeer but it's not behaving like that. It's giving the currently running device sdk Version. Not the version mentioned in build.gradle. that is what I mentioned in the question also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want you can also declare it in your gradle like:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "some name"
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        buildConfigField "int", "MIN_SDK_VERSION", "$minSdkVersion.apiLevel"
}
```

then in your code you just need to get it like:

```
BuildConf.MIN_SDK_VERSION
```

Comment: Thanks. This one helped me.

Comment: I had to do this way to make it work: `buildConfigField "int", "MIN_SDK_VERSION", "$minSdkVersion.apiLevel"`

Comment: API level 24 introduced the `minSdkVersion` field on `ApplicationInfo` but you have to use this answer to support older devices unfortunately.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `BuildConfig.MIN_SDK_VERSION`? With `BuildConfig` instead of `BuildConf`?

Answer (score 3):

> targetSdkVersion : The minimum SDK version this application targets

```
int targetSdkVersion= 0;
IPackageManager manager = AppGlobals.getPackageManager();
try {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = manager.getApplicationInfo(appName, 0);
    if (applicationInfo != null) {
      targetSdkVersion= applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;
    }
}
```

You can get more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#targetSdkVersion

Comment: As i told in the question itself the applicationinfo `targetSdkVersion` providing the current version of the device which the app is running. it is not providing the targetsdk version mentioned in the build.gradle. @pedroagsantos answer solved my question.

Answer (score 2):

@PedroAGSantos's answer is not 100% correct, we need to use apiLevel property of minSdkVersion and we don't need extra quotes. here is the corrected version:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "some name"
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        buildConfigField "int", "MIN_SDK_VERSION", "$minSdkVersion.apiLevel"
}
```

Comment: instead of give multiple answer, just try to edit answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get minimum SDK and target SDK version during runtime

```
PackageManager packageM = getPackageManager();
String packageName = getPackageName();
int targetVersion = 0, minVersion = 0;
PackageInfo info = null;
try {
   info = packageM.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
   ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = info.applicationInfo;
   targetVersion = applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;
   minVersion = applicationInfo.minSdkVersion;
   ......
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Shorted way:

```
int minimumSDK = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().minSdkVersion;
int targSDK = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion;
```